# Рандомный вывод некскольких чисел

Tags: php, html

как можно вывести несколько РАЗНЫХ чисел?

`$rand = rand(1, 35)
echo $rand; 
echo $rand;
echo $rand;`

пользуюсь такой функцией для вывода чисел ОТ 1 ДО 35
за один раз функция выводит лишь одно число, а мне нужно, чтобы числа были разные.

***То есть мне нужно, чтобы получилось так:***

> "**1,30,24**" (**разные** рандомные числа, в любой последовательности ***от 1 до 35***)

, а получается так:

> "21,21,21" (числа повторяются)

если, что то извените, что я дуб в програмировании...

Comment: Так и делайте echo rand(1, 35)

Comment: святой человек :-D)))) я что-то сильно тупанул прямо просто. целые сутки думал, а ответ оказался прост..))) спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

функция rand отрабатывает один раз в скрипте и вы ее значение записываете в переменную $rand и просто выводите ее три раза (поэтому числа одинаковые)
можно три раза вызвать rand(1, 35), как вам уже написали выше.
Но есть вероятность что в при какой-то генерации числа могут совпасть.
Вариантов много.
Один из них:

```
$array = range(0, 35); // создаем массив от 1 до 35
shuffle($array); // перемешиваем
array_walk(array_slice($array, 0, 3), function ($v) { echo $v . "<br />"; }); // выводим первые три элемента
```

Comment: Спасибо) думаю можно попробывать

Answer (score 1):

так и делайте echo rand(1, 35)

> `echo rand(1, 35) 
>   echo rand(1, 35) 
>   echo rand(1, 35)`

(автор:MoloF)